# Filter by Date Difference in LINQ using EF

Tags: linq, entity-framework, date

I need to filter a record set like

OrderShippedDate - 20 days  <-- Get all orders with a ShippedDate 20 days ago

```
var orders = ctx.Orders.Where(p => p.OrderShippedDate == 20) <---??? not sure what I need here .ToList();
```

How do I do a date diff in EF / LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you work out your parameters locally, and then pass those in. It's not clear from your description whether you mean *exactly* 20 days ago, *more* than 20 days ago, or *less* than 20 days ago, which makes it hard to give you concrete advice, but if it's "more than 20 days ago" you might use something like:

```
var upperBound = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-20);
var orders = ctx.Orders.Where(p => p.OrderShippedDate < upperBound);
```